# How to wait for firebase cloud function to complete before calling next function? (AngularFire)

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I have a sign-up function `submit()` that calls a `signup()`function in my authentication service, which is basically AngularFirebase `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...)` . When it has been completed, another function `updateUserDocument` from my data service is called. This function looks for the user document in Firebase Firestore. That document is created by a cloud function, `functions.auth.user().onCreate(user.createProfile)` and is triggered when an auth object is created.

Using a cloud function is a convenient way to set all the initial user properties. The cloud function also makes it simple for me to implement sign-up with providers such as Google and Facebook.

However, the problem is that the cloud function does not have time to complete before the `updateUserDocument` function gets called and this results in it not finding the document in Firestore.

*QUESTION: What is a good way to wait for the cloud function to complete before running `updateUserDocument`. Can I emit some kind of event from the cloud function, and if so, how do I listen to it client-side?*

**Submit function (in /sign-up.ts)**

```
  submit() {
    if (!this.signUpForm.valid) {
      return;
    }

    const {displayName, email, password } = this.signUpForm.value;
    this.auth.signUp(email, password).pipe(
      switchMap(({ user: { uid } }) => this.dataService.updateUserDocument({ uid, email, displayName: displayName })),
      this.toast.observe({
        success: 'Congrats! You are all signed up',
        loading: 'Signing up...',
        error: ({ message }) => `${message}`
      })
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/create-profile']);
      this.openVerticallyCentered('Welcome!')
    });
  }
```

**Cloud function (in functions/src/user/index.ts)**

```
export const createProfile = async (userRecord: any) => {
    const uid = userRecord.uid;
    const email = userRecord.email;
    const photoURL = userRecord.photoUrl || '';
    const displayName = userRecord.displayName || '';
    const firstName = userRecord.firstName || '';
    const lastName = userRecord.lastName || '';
    const country = userRecord.country || '';
    const dateOfBirth = userRecord.dateOfBirth || '';
    const address = userRecord.address || '';
    const suburb = userRecord.suburb || '';
    const state = userRecord.state || '';
    const postCode = userRecord.postCode || '';
    const homePhone = userRecord.homePhone || '';
    const mobilePhone = userRecord.mobilePhone || '';
    const memNum = userRecord.memNum || '';
    const memDueDate = userRecord.memDueDate || '';
    const timestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    const memType = userRecord.memType || '';
    const memStatus = userRecord.memStatus || '';
    const isAdmin = userRecord.isAdmin || false
    //const newUserRef = db.doc(`users/${uid}`)

    // Convert any date to timestamp for consistency

    try {
        return await db
            .collection(`users`)
            .doc(userRecord.uid)
            .set({
                uid: uid,
                email: email,
                photoURL: photoURL,
                displayName: displayName,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                country: country,
                dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth,
                address: address,
                suburb: suburb,
                state: state,
                postCode: postCode,
                homePhone: homePhone,
                mobilePhone: mobilePhone,
                memNum: memNum,
                memType: memType,
                memStatus: memStatus,
                memDueDate: memDueDate,
                lastLoginDate: timestamp,
                joined: timestamp,
                updated: timestamp,
                isAdmin: isAdmin,
            });
    } catch (message) {
        return console.error(message);
    }
};
```

**index file for exporting function to firebase function (/functions/user/index)**

```
exports.authOnCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user.createProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying of a trigger in the backend, I would use a cloud functions (maybe a callable function) to do that logic.

In the "signup" cloud function I would do both things, create the account with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and set the profile in `updateUserDocument`.